# How to modify UIDatePicker to get rid of era being shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, nscalendar

When I set UIDatePickder calendar type to Arabic calendar like below

```
NSCalendar *hijriQamariCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCivilCalendar];
[self.resultCalendarOutlet setCalendar:hijriQamariCalendar];
```

I get era also displayed in the UIDatePikcer. I am looking for a way to either have the era removed from the UIDatePicker from being displayed or customize its value/text.

**UIDatePicker with Arabic Calendar showing era:**

[image: UIDatePicker with Arabic Calendar]

Please see the given images. I am not sure if this is possible first. However, UIDatePicker for Gregorian calendar doesn't display any era information.

**UIDatePicker with Gregorian Calendar - No era :**

[image: UIDatePicker with Gregorian Calendar]

which is fine for me.